# Android use AsyncTask communication is not working

Tags: android, spring, server

I'm trying to do Spring asynchronous communication.

I wrote the code, communication works, but both spring and android data values ​​are null.

why?

```
btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                String id=edit_email.getText().toString();
                String password=edit_password.getText().toString();

                ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
                values.put("id",id);
                values.put("password",password);

                NetworkTask net=new NetworkTask("http://10.0.2.2:8080/Pet_Tuen_Tuen/login.do",values);
                net.execute();

                //new NetworkTask2().execute(values);

                if(check==1) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        String url;
        ContentValues values;

        NetworkTask(String url, ContentValues values){
            this.url = url;
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //progress bar를 보여주는 등등의 행위
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String result;
            RequestHttpURLConnection requestHttpURLConnection = new RequestHttpURLConnection();
            result = requestHttpURLConnection.request(url, values);
            return result; // 결과가 여기에 담깁니다. 아래 onPostExecute()의 파라미터로 전달됩니다.
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // 통신이 완료되면 호출됩니다.
            // 결과에 따른 UI 수정 등은 여기서 합니다.

            try {
                check=1;
                Log.println(Log.DEBUG, "------------------", result);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Request Connection code.

```
public class RequestHttpURLConnection {
    public String request(String _url, ContentValues _params) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;

        // URL 뒤에 붙여서 보낼 파라미터.
        StringBuffer sbParams = new StringBuffer();

        /**
         * 1. StringBuffer에 파라미터 연결
         * */
        // 보낼 데이터가 없으면 파라미터를 비운다.
        if (_params == null)
            sbParams.append("");
            // 보낼 데이터가 있으면 파라미터를 채운다.
        else {
            // 파라미터가 2개 이상이면 파라미터 연결에 &가 필요하므로 스위칭할 변수 생성.
            boolean isAnd = false;
            // 파라미터 키와 값.
            String key;
            String value;

            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> parameter : _params.valueSet()) {
                key = parameter.getKey();
                value = parameter.getValue().toString();
                Log.println(Log.DEBUG,"=================>",value);
                // 파라미터가 두개 이상일때, 파라미터 사이에 &를 붙인다.
                if (isAnd)
                    sbParams.append("&");

                sbParams.append(key).append("=").append(value);

                // 파라미터가 2개 이상이면 isAnd를 true로 바꾸고 다음 루프부터 &를 붙인다.
                if (!isAnd)
                    if (_params.size() >= 2)
                        isAnd = true;
            }
        }

        /**
         * 2. HttpURLConnection을 통해 web의 데이터를 가져온다.
         * */
        try {
            URL url = new URL(_url);
            urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // [2-1]. urlConn 설정.
            urlConn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST"); // URL 요청에 대한 메소드 설정 : GET/POST.
            urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConn.setDoInput(true);
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8"); // Accept-Charset 설정.
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Context_Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            // [2-2]. parameter 전달 및 데이터 읽어오기.
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream()));
            pw.write(sbParams.toString());
            pw.flush(); // 출력 스트림을 flush. 버퍼링 된 모든 출력 바이트를 강제 실행.
            pw.close(); // 출력 스트림을 닫고 모든 시스템 자원을 해제.

            // [2-3]. 연결 요청 확인.
            // 실패 시 null을 리턴하고 메서드를 종료.
            if (urlConn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                return null;

            // [2-4]. 읽어온 결과물 리턴.
            // 요청한 URL의 출력물을 BufferedReader로 받는다.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            // 출력물의 라인과 그 합에 대한 변수.
            String line;
            String page = "";

            // 라인을 받아와 합친다.
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                page += line;
            }
            return page;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) { // for URL.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) { // for openConnection().
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConn != null)
                urlConn.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

spring code

```
@Controller
public class MemberController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login.do",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public JSONObject login(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println(request.getAttribute("id"));
        System.out.println(request.getAttribute("password"));


        JSONObject attr=new JSONObject();
        attr.put("msg","ok");

        return attr;
    }
}
```

There is an error at run time.

But in spring data value is null.

Force sending data from spring to android but it is also null.

Why is the data not going over?
Communication is done by post.

Answer (score 0):

Value needs to be URL encoded:

```
sbParams.append(key).append("=").append(URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));

-------------------------------

urlConn.setReadTimeout(10000);
urlConn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
urlConn.setDoInput(true);
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");.
urlConn.connect();
```

Still if not work then try

```
request.getParameter("id");
```